# How to write my own applications on Docker?

Tags: docker

I've just started trying to use Docker as container to develop my applications.

But I've still have some question. After I setup my environment on Docker, how do I do some command like cloning git repositories from github, or write my own application after I enter vagrant on Docker?

Or am I using Docker in a wrong way?

Using node-opencv as an example:

https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv

I've enter

```
docker pull shykes/node-opencv
docker run shykes/node-opencv node -e "console.log(require('opencv').version)"
```

and it all works well, and I know that Docker have setup the environment for me.  But how do I write my own applications using this environment?

Do I need to install another vim, or git? Can Docker read the flies I've build outside Docker?

This really frustrated me ...thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest and normal way is to use Dockerfiles.  You could use shykes/node-opencv in a FROM http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/builder/#from to use his image as a starting point and then in that Dockerfile `ADD` your own files.

See http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/builder/#dockerfile-examples

Alternatively you can run a series of commands separated with ";" on the `run` command line.  Or you can run `bash` on the container, then `docker commit` the changes, and `run` again with your program installed.

Anyway just stick with the `build` command on a Dockerfile.  Yes Docker can read external files with `ADD`.

Comment: Thanks, I've another question. What is the best way for me to edit a file using sublime? I want to edit the file in docker environment (`bash` on the container) but using sublime (on my `bash` outside the container) how do I achieve it?

Comment: Just edit the file on your local computer and then use `ADD` in the Dockerfile.

If you really needed to edit it inside the container, you would install sshd on the container and then use sshfs http://almar.io/2013/02/remote-editing-sublime-text-sshfs/.  Search google or stack overflow for running sshd in a docker container.  Actually your question should be in a separate question on stack overflow.

Comment: I've accepted your advice and open up a new question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088815/editing-files-using-sublime-in-docker, thanks!